# sql issue with parameter 6

Tags: java, sql, database

Hello guys I'm still new to Java programming.

I have a problem NO VALUE Specified for parameter 6. I'm still searching for the problem. Can you guys help me?

Here's my code

```
if (newdata == true) {       
  int p = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you really to SAVE?","INSERT",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION );
    if(checkInputs() && ImgPath != null && ImgPath2 != null)
    {
        try {
             Connection con = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mmis(ID,Name,Condi,Image,Image2,Price,Buyfrom,Date)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

            ps.setString(1, txt_ID.getText());
            ps.setString(2, txt_Name.getText());
            ps.setString(3, txt_Condi.getText());

            InputStream img = new FileInputStream(new File(ImgPath));
            ps.setBlob(4, img);
            InputStream img1 = new FileInputStream(new File(ImgPath2));
            ps.setBlob(5, img1);
            ps.executeUpdate();

            ps.setString(6, txt_Price.getText());
            ps.setString(7, txt_Buyfrom.getText());
            ps.setString(8, txt_Date.getText());

            Show_MosqueManagementSystem_In_JTable();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "DATA INSERTED");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());


    }
                  }
      else{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "One Or More Field Are Empty");
    }
}                                          
}
```

Comment: Set String(s) 6-8 before calling executeUpdate.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting 5 parameters before calling `ps.executeUpdate`. Your query expects all 8 to be set. See the question marks here

```
PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mmis(ID,Name,Condi,Image,Image2,Price,Buyfrom,Date)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

You should call your query after all params are set. In other words, change this:

```
        ps.setBlob(5, img1);
        ps.executeUpdate();

        ps.setString(6, txt_Price.getText());
        ps.setString(7, txt_Buyfrom.getText());
        ps.setString(8, txt_Date.getText());
```

To this:

```
        ps.setBlob(5, img1);
        ps.setString(6, txt_Price.getText());
        ps.setString(7, txt_Buyfrom.getText());
        ps.setString(8, txt_Date.getText());

        ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 1):

You shall `execute update` after setting all parameters, not before that.

```
        InputStream img = new FileInputStream(new File(ImgPath));
        ps.setBlob(4, img);
        InputStream img1 = new FileInputStream(new File(ImgPath2));
        ps.setBlob(5, img1);

        ps.setString(6, txt_Price.getText());
        ps.setString(7, txt_Buyfrom.getText());
        ps.setString(8, txt_Date.getText());
        // Shall execute update after setting all parameters
        ps.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `ps.executeUpdate()` before you bind the values for parameter 6 (and 7, and 8, for that matter). Just move that call after all the parameter settings, and you should be fine.